# Why do I keep getting an error with my tab function?

Tags: javascript, html

i was restyling my content in my first tab and when I finished, I noticed that when I switched to other tabs the content didn't display. I looked in the console and saw that i was getting an error from my switch tabs function at my "tabToActivate.classList.add("content-active");" line. I'm not sire why this is happening. I haven't changed anything in my js.

```
settings.js:212 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (settings.js:212:21)
```

```
function switchTabs() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const menuBar = link.parentElement;
      const tabsContainer = menuBar.parentElement;
      const tabNumber = link.dataset.forTab;
      const tabToActivate = tabsContainer.querySelector(
        `[data-tab="${tabNumber}"]`
      );

      menuBar.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach((link) => {
        link.classList.remove("tab-button-active");
      });

      tabsContainer.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach((tab) => {
        tab.classList.remove("content-active");
      });
      link.classList.add("tab-button-active");

      tabToActivate.classList.add("content-active");
    });
  });

  document.querySelectorAll(".vtab-button").forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const menuBar = link.parentElement;
      const menuTab = menuBar.parentElement;
      const tabsContainer = menuTab.parentElement;
      const tabNumber = link.dataset.forTab;
      const tabToActivate = tabsContainer.querySelector(
        `[data-tab="${tabNumber}"]`
      );

      menuBar.querySelectorAll(".vtab-button").forEach((link) => {
        link.classList.remove(".vtab-button-active");
      });

      tabsContainer.querySelectorAll(".myroom-content-main").forEach((tab) => {
        tab.classList.remove("myroom-content-main-active");
      });
      link.classList.add("vtab-button-active");

      tabToActivate.classList.add("myroom-content-main-active");
    });
  });
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>StudioPick</title>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!---Bootstrap CSS--->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/settings.css">
</head>

<body>
    
    <main class="main">
        <div class="responsive-wrapper">
            <div class="main-header">
                <h1 id="users-header">
                    <!---This is where the profile name is being displayed--->
                </h1>
                <h2 class="rating">Rating:</h2>
                <img class="star" src="Images/Star.png">
                <h2 id="current-rating">4.00</h2>
                <div class="search">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                    <button type="submit">
                        <i class="ph-magnifying-glass-bold"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="horizontal-tabs">
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="1">Dashboard</a>
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="2">Payment History</a>
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="3">Session Management</a>
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="4">My Rooms</a>
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="5">Edit Profile</a>
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="6">Edit Payment</a>
            </div>

            <!---Tab 1--->
            <div class="content" data-tab="1">
                <div class="content-header">
                    <div class="content-header-intro">
                        <h2>Studio Overview</h2>
                        <p>View your current appointments and the status of your studio.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content-main-wrapper">
                    <div class="content-main">

                        <!---Calendar--->
                        <div class="calendar">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Schedule</strong></h5>
                            </div>




                            <button class="calendar-view">View Full Calendar</button>
                        </div>
                        <!---Calendar--->
                        <!---Current Session--->
                        <div class="session-info">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Current Session</strong></h5>
                                <div class="current-client">


                                </div>
                                <p class="current-date text-muted">Date:</p>
                                <p class="todays-date">08/30/2022</p>
                                <p class="current-service text-muted">Service:</p>
                                <p class="todays-service">W Engineer</p>
                                <p class="current-room text-muted">Room:</p>
                                <p class="todays-room">A</p>
                                <p class="current-duration text-muted">Duration:</p>
                                <p class="todays-duration">3 hours</p>
                                <p class="current-start-time text-muted">Start Time:</p>
                                <p class="todays-start-time">4:00 pm</p>
                                <p class="current-end-time text-muted">End Time:</p>
                                <p class="todays-end-time">7:00 pm</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!---Current Session--->
                        <!---Upcoming Sessions--->
                        <div class="sessions">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Upcoming Session</strong></h5>
                                <div class="new-session">
                                    <div class="actions-group">
                                        <p class="actions">Actions:</p>
                                        <button class="accept">Accept</button>
                                        <button class="reject">Reject</button>
                                        <button class="reschedule">Reschedule</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="session-price">$100</p>
                                    <p class="customer-name">Grmln!</p>
                                    <p class="session-room text-muted">Room A: </p>
                                    <p class="session-type text-muted">No Engineer</p>
                                    <p class="session-length text-muted">2:00 pm - 4:00 pm</p>
                                    <p class="session-date text-muted">08/27/2022</p>
                                </div>
                                <button class="upcoming-view">View Upcoming Sessions</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!---Upcoming Sessions--->
                        <!---Payment History--->
                        <div class="pending-sessions">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Payment History</strong></h5>
                                <div class="pending">
                                    <p class="pending-session-price">$100</p>
                                    <p class="stripe text-muted">~ Stripe</p>
                                    <p class="pending-customer-name">Joony</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pending2">
                                    <p class="pending-session-price">$100</p>
                                    <p class="stripe text-muted">~ Stripe</p>
                                    <p class="pending-customer-name">Highway</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <button class="pending-view">View Pending Sessions</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!---Payment History--->
                    <!---Messages--->
                    <div class="messages">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Messages</strong></h5>
                            <div class="notification-one">
                                <p class="person-one">Chris Brown</p>
                                <p class="text-one text-muted">I'm omw. 20 mins out. I ran into some traffic bc of this
                                    real bad accident. If I don't get there in time, I'll pay extra. </p>
                                <p class="time-occurred-one text-muted">3 min ago</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="notification-two">
                                <p class="person-one">Kanye West</p>
                                <p class="text-one text-muted">I'm omw. 45 mins out. I ran into some traffic bc of this
                                    real bad accident. If I don't get there in time, I'll pay extra. </p>
                                <p class="time-occurred-one text-muted">12 min ago</p>
                            </div>
                            <button class="view-messages">View Messages</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!---Messages--->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---Tab 1--->

        <!---Tab 2--->
        <div class="content" data-tab="2">
            <div class="content-header">
                <div class="content-header-intro">
                    <h2>View past transactions</h2>
                    <p>Here is where you can view your previous transactions.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main-wrapper">
                <div class="content-main">
                    <div class="wrapper">

                        <div class="row mt-2 pt-2">
                            <div class="col-md-6" id="income">
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
                                    <i class="bi bi-safe" style="color:#03af00"></i>
                                    <p class="text mx-3" style="color:#A388E7">Income</p>
                                    <p class="ml-4 money" style="color:#03af00">$9,758.23</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-responsive mt-3">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Activity</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Mode</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-right">Amount</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td scope="row"> <span class="fa fa-briefcase mr-1"></span> Coorg Trip </td>
                                        <td><span class="fa fa-cc-mastercard"></span></td>
                                        <td class="text-muted">12 Jul 2020, 12:30 PM</td>
                                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center"> <span
                                                class="fa fa-long-arrow-up mr-1"></span> $52.9 </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td scope="row"> <span class="fa fa-bed mr-1"></span> Hotel Leela Palace
                                        </td>
                                        <td><span class="fa fa-cc-mastercard"></span></td>
                                        <td class="text-muted">11 Jul 2020, 2:00 PM</td>
                                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center"> <span
                                                class="fa fa-long-arrow-up mr-1"></span> $18.9 </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td scope="row"> <span class="fa fa-exchange mr-1"></span> Monthly Salary
                                        </td>
                                        <td><span class="fa fa-cc-visa"></span></td>
                                        <td class="text-muted">10 Jul 2020, 8:30 PM</td>
                                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center"> <span
                                                class="fa fa-long-arrow-down mr-1"></span> $9,765.00 </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td scope="row"> <span class="fa fa-exchange mr-1"></span> Xbox Purchase
                                        </td>
                                        <td><span class="fa fa-cc-mastercard"></span></td>
                                        <td class="text-muted">12 May 2020, 4:30 PM</td>
                                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center"> <span
                                                class="fa fa-long-arrow-up mr-1"></span> $198.90 </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td scope="row"> <span class="fa fa-cutlery mr-1"></span> Dinner Party </td>
                                        <td><span class="fa fa-cc-visa"></span></td>
                                        <td class="text-muted">11 May 2020, 5:30 PM</td>
                                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center"> <span
                                                class="fa fa-long-arrow-up mr-1"></span> $12.90 </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td scope="row"> <span class="fa fa-briefcase mr-1"></span> Nandini Hills
                                            Ride </td>
                                        <td><span class="fa fa-cc-mastercard"></span></td>
                                        <td class="text-muted">10 May 2020, 01:30 PM</td>
                                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center"> <span
                                                class="fa fa-long-arrow-up mr-1"></span> $97.9 </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td scope="row"> <span class="fa fa-briefcase mr-1"></span> Goa Beach Party
                                        </td>
                                        <td><span class="fa fa-cc-visa"></span></td>
                                        <td class="text-muted">09 May 2020, 01:30 PM</td>
                                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center"> <span
                                                class="fa fa-long-arrow-up mr-1"></span> $97.9 </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center results"> <span
                                class="pl-md-3">Showing<b class="text-white"> 1-7 0f 200 </b> trasactions</span>
                            <div class="pt-3">
                                <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                                    <ul class="pagination">
                                        <li class="page-item disabled"> <a class="page-link" href="#"
                                                aria-label="Previous"> <span aria-hidden="true">&lt;</span> </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="page-item"> <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&gt;</span> </a> </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!---Tab 2--->
        <!---Tab 3--->
        <div class="content" data-tab="3">
            <div class="content-header">
                <div class="content-header-intro">
                    <h2>Session Management</h2>
                    <p>View or modify current and past sessions.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main-wrapper">
                <div class="content-main">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---Tab 3--->
        <!---Tab 4--->
        <div class="content" data-tab="4">
            <div class="content-header">
                <div class="content-header-intro">
                    <h2>Manage your studio rooms</h2>
                    <p>Add, delete, and edit the room images and prices for your studio profile.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main-wrapper">
                <div class="content-panel">
                    <div class="vertical-tabs">
                        <a class="vtab-button" data-for-tab="1" href="#">View Rooms</a>
                        <a class="vtab-button" data-for-tab="2" href="#">Manage Services</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="myroom-content-main" data-tab="1">
                    <div class="card-grid">
                        <article class="card1 text-white card-has-bg click-col"
                            style="background-image:url('https://westlakepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/SnoopDoggStudio.jpg');">
                            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <p class="roomName">Room Name</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                        <article class="card2 text-white card-has-bg click-col"
                            style="background-image:url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5ca54e7f94d71a062d6042ac/1626463286614-7KC9NDHQVCEOYG0PRSFD/1390510159024.jpeg');">
                            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <p class="roomName">Room Name</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="myroom-content-main" data-tab="2">
                    <!-- Card One -->
                    <h1 class="roomcard-head text-muted">Select a price to edit:</h1>
                    <div class="roomcard">
                        <div class="roomcard-content">
                            <h2 class="price-roomName">Room A
                                <br>
                                Services
                                <br>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="service">
                                <button class="serviceEdit" id="edit10" value="edit10">edit</button>
                                <button class="serviceSave" type="submit" id="save10" value="save10"
                                    onclick="updateService()">Save</button>
                                <button class="serviceCancel" id="cancel10" value="cancel10">Cancel</button>
                                <p class="serviceInfo" id="serviceInfo">Studio Session W/ No Engineer</p>
                                <div class="col-auto">
                                    <input type="text" id="editService" class="editService">
                                </div>

                                <div id="moneySet">
                                    <button class="priceEdit" id="edit11" value="edit11">edit</button>
                                    <button class="priceSave" type="submit" id="save11" value="save11"
                                        onclick="updatePrice()">Save</button>
                                    <button class="priceCancel" id="cancel11" value="cancel11">Cancel</button>
                                    <p class="money">$</p>
                                    <P class="servicePrice" id="servicePrice">45</P>
                                    <p class="slash">/</p>
                                    <p class="time">Hr</p>
                                    <div class="center" id="plus-minusInput">
                                        <div class="input-group" id="changePrice">
                                            <span class="input-group-btn" id="minus">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number"
                                                    data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="text" name="quant[1]" id="numberInput" value="0" min="0"
                                                max="200">
                                            <span class="input-group-btn" id="plus">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number"
                                                    data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="button-text text-muted">Change Price Value</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Card One -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---Tab 4--->
        <!---Tab 5--->
        <div class="content" data-tab="5">
            <div class="content-header">
                <div class="content-header-intro">
                    <h2>Manage your profile</h2>
                    <p>Edit your profile information such email, username, password, etc.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main-wrapper">
                <div class="content-main">
                    <div class="first-name">
                        <h3>First Name</h3>
                        <p class="firstName text-muted" id="firstName">User's First Name</p>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="text" id="inputFirst" class="editInput">
                        </div>
                        <button class="edit" id="edit" value="edit">Edit</button>
                        <button class="save" type="submit" id="save" value="save" onclick="updateFirst()">Save</button>
                        <button class="cancel" id="cancel" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-text">
                    <div class="last-name">
                        <h3>Last Name</h3>
                        <p class="lastName text-muted" id="lastName">User's Last Name</p>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="text" id="inputLast" class="editInput">
                        </div>
                        <button class="edit" id="edit2" value="edit2">Edit</button>
                        <button class="save" type="submit2" id="save2" value="save2"
                            onclick="updateLast()">Save</button>
                        <button class="cancel" id="cancel2" value="cancel2">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-text">
                    <div class="email-address">
                        <h3>Email Address</h3>
                        <p class="email text-muted" id="email">User's Email Address</p>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="editInput">
                        </div>
                        <button class="edit" id="edit3" value="edit3">Edit</button>
                        <button class="save" type="submit" id="save3" value="save3"
                            onclick="updateEmail()">Save</button>
                        <button class="cancel" id="cancel3" value="cancel3">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-text">
                    <div class="user-name">
                        <h3>Studio Name</h3>
                        <p class="studio-name text-muted" id="studioName">User's Studio Name</p>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="text" id="inputName" class="editInput">
                        </div>
                        <button class="edit" id="edit4" value="edit4">Edit</button>
                        <button class="save" type="submit" id="save4" value="save4" onclick="updateStu()">Save</button>
                        <button class="cancel" id="cancel4" value="cancel4">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-text">
                    <div class="phone-number">
                        <h3>Phone Number</h3>
                        <p class="phoneNumber text-muted" id="phoneNumber">User's Phone Number</p>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="text" id="inputNumber" class="editInput">
                        </div>
                        <button class="edit" id="edit5" value="edit5">Edit</button>
                        <button class="save" type="submit" id="save5" value="save5"
                            onclick="updatePhone()">Save</button>
                        <button class="cancel" id="cancel5" value="cancel5">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-text">
                    <div class="studio-address">
                        <h3>Studio Address</h3>
                        <p class="stuAddress text-muted" id="stuAddress">User's Studio Address</p>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="text" id="inputAddress" class="editInput">
                        </div>
                        <button class="edit" id="edit6" value="edit6">Edit</button>
                        <button class="save" type="submit" id="save6" value="save6">Save</button>
                        <button class="cancel" id="cancel6" value="cancel6">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-text">
                    <div class="studio-state">
                        <h3>State</h3>
                        <p class="stuState text-muted" id="stuState">User's State</p>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="text" id="inputState" class="editInput">
                        </div>
                        <button class="edit" id="edit7" value="edit7">Edit</button>
                        <button class="save" type="submit" id="save7" value="save7">Save</button>
                        <button class="cancel" id="cancel7" value="cancel7">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-text">
                    <div class="studio-country">
                        <h3>Country</h3>
                        <p class="stuCountry text-muted" id="stuCountry">User's Country</p>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="text" id="inputCountry" class="editInput">
                        </div>
                        <button class="edit" id="edit8" value="edit8">Edit</button>
                        <button class="save" type="submit" id="save8" value="save8">Save</button>
                        <button class="cancel" id="cancel8" value="cancel8">Cancel</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="profile-image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img class="card-img-bottom"
                                src="https://www.bakefromscratch.com/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder.png">
                            <button class="edit" id="edit9" value="edit9">Edit</button>
                            <button class="save" type="submit" id="save9" value="save9">Save</button>
                            <button class="cancel" id="cancel9" value="cancel9">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---Tab 5--->
        <!---Tab 6--->
        <div class="content" data-tab="6">
            <div class="content-header">
                <div class="content-header-intro">
                    <h2>Manage your payment methods</h2>
                    <p>Edit, add, and delete new credit/debit cards.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content-header-actions">
                    <a href="#" class="button">
                        <i class="ph-faders-bold"></i>
                        <span>Filters</span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="button">
                        <i class="ph-plus-bold"></i>
                        <span>Add a new card</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main-wrapper">
                <div class="content-main">
                    <div class="card-grid">
                        <h1 class="card1-head text-muted">Payment One</h1>
                        <!-- Card One -->
                        <div class="ccard">
                            <div class="credit-card visa selectable">
                                <input class="cardSelector" type="radio" name="primaryCard">
                                <div class="credit-card-last4">
                                    4242
                                </div>
                                <div class="credit-card-expiry">
                                    08/25
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Card One -->
                        <!-- Card Two -->
                        <h1 class="card2-head text-muted">Payment Two</h1>
                        <div class="ccard2">
                            <div class="credit-card2 visa selectable">
                                <input class="cardSelector" type="radio" name="primaryCard">
                                <div class="credit-card2-last4">
                                    5632
                                </div>
                                <div class="credit-card2-expiry">
                                    11/28
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Card Two -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---Tab 6--->

        <!---Footer--->
        <footer class="my-5 pt-5 text-muted text-center text-small">
            <p class="mb-1">© 2022 StudioPick.</p>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
        <!---Footer--->

        </div>
    </main>

    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-database.js"></script>


    <!---Javascript--->
    <script src="Javascript/settings.js"></script>
    <!---Javascript--->

    <!----More Bootstrap--->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!----More Bootstrap--->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you at least know that the error is telling you that `tabToActivate` is `null`? The [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) tells you when `querySelector` returns `null`. _“I haven't changed anything in my js.”_ — The error is caused by incorrect _HTML_, which you haven’t shown.

Comment: I added my html. the only thing I changed was the content in tab 1

Comment: Your indents look off. I think your HTML may be malformed but there's a bit too much of it to tell at a glance

Comment: I used a linter and it said you have an extra `</div>`, just before `</main>`. Please fix your HTML before continuing